# Faithful Idempotent Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, and let $M$ be a faithful multiplication module (namely, $xM=0$ for $x\in R$ gives $x=0$, and any submodule equals $IM$ for some ideal of $R$). If $IM=I^2M$, is it true that $I=I^2$ necessarily?

Of course, the faithfulness is a necessary condition as seen in  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085865/idempotent-modules-and-ideals?noredirect=1#comment4290093_2085865). Thanks for any suggestion!